# A consequence of the Min-Max Principle for self-adjoint operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $H=(H, (\cdot, \cdot))$ be a Hilbert space. Let $T_1,T_2:D \subset H \longrightarrow H$ be a self-adjoint operators (not necessarily bounded). It's well-know that the spectrum $\sigma(T_i)$ of $T_i$ satisfies $\sigma(T_i) \subset \mathbb{R}$, for $i=1,2$ (see Theorem $29.2$ in $[3]$). Suppose that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are bounded below and has $N \in \mathbb{N}$ (real) eigenvalues arranged in the ascending order
$$
\lambda_1(T_i) \leq \lambda_2(T_i) \leq \lambda_3(T_i) \leq \cdots \lambda_N(T_i), \quad i \in \{1,2\}.
$$

As a consequence of the Min-Max Principle $($see $[2$, page $85]$ or $[1$, page $61])$, if
$$
(T_1(u), u) \leq (T_2(u), u),\; \forall \; u \in D \tag{1}
$$
then,  for each $n \in \{1,\cdots, N\}$,
$$\lambda_n(T_1) \leq \lambda_n(T_2). \tag{2}$$

**Question.** If
$$
(T_1(u), u) < (T_2(u), u),\; \forall \; u \in D\setminus \{0\}
$$
and
then
$$\lambda_n(T_1) < \lambda_n(T_2) \tag{3}
$$ for each $n \in \{1,\cdots, N\}$?

I think so, because the Min-Max Principle establishes that, for $i=1,2$,
$$
\lambda_n(T_i)= \sup_{u_1, u_2, \cdots u_{n-1} \in H } \inf_{v \in D\setminus \{0\} \atop v \in [u_1, u_2, \cdots u_{n-1}]^{\perp} } \frac{(T_i(v),v)}{\|v\|}.
$$

**Remark.** I did this question in [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246725/a-consequence-of-the-min-max-principle-for-self-adjoint-operators), but I don't received any comment or answer.

Any comment or reference are welcome.

$[1]$  Kato, T., Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators, $2$nd edition, Springer, Berlin, $1984$.

$[2]$ Reed, S. and Simon, B., Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics: Analysis of Operator,
Academic Press, Vol. IV, $1978$.

$[3]$ Bachman, G. and Narici, L. Functional Analysis. New York: Academic Press, $1966$.

Comment: Yes, and the proof is the same as in the other case (eq. (1)): For example, if $T_2 v=\lambda_1(T_2)v$, then $\lambda_1(T_1)\le \langle v, T_1 v\rangle < \lambda_1(T_2)$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Great comment! Can you put your comment as an answer? If possible with more details in order to help the community.

Comment: @ChristianRemling But why $\lambda_1(T_1)\le \langle v, T_1 v\rangle < \lambda_1(T_2)$? The first inequality I don't see because we have $\sup \inf$ and the second because $ \langle v, T_1 v\rangle <  \langle v, T_2 v\rangle =\lambda_1 \|v\|^2$.

Comment: Min-max principle indeed yields this. What is the question then?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Can you give more details because yields?

Comment: Your formula for $\lambda_n$ yields it immediately: for fixed $u_i$'s you may compare inner infima

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry, I didn't understand your argument. Could you give more details?

Comment: Start with $(T_1v,v)/\|v\|^2\leqslant (T_2v,v)/\|v\|^2$. Then pass to infimum and get $\inf_{v \in D\setminus \{0\} \atop v \in [u_1, u_2, \cdots u_{n-1}]^{\perp} } \frac{(T_1(v),v)}{\|v\|^2}\leqslant \inf_{v \in D\setminus \{0\} \atop v \in [u_1, u_2, \cdots u_{n-1}]^{\perp} } \frac{(T_2(v),v)}{\|v\|^2}$. Then pass to supremum to get $\lambda_n(T_1)\leqslant \lambda_n(T_2)$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov But my question is if $\lambda_n(T_1) < \lambda_n(T_2)$ holds, that is, if the strict inequality occurs. See the **Question**, please.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think that your argument is valid only for $\lambda_1$, because it seems me that  $\lambda_1(T_1)\le \langle v, T_1 v\rangle $ holds only for the first eigenvalue (see for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_theorem) )

Comment: @Guilherme: Yes, there's more involved for $n>1$, but it still works in roughly the same way. I wrote an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm expanding my comment, in response to the OP's comment. Indeed, the case of just the lowest eigenvalue is perhaps not a good illustration of the full argument.

In general, let $u_j$ be a normalized eigenvector for $\lambda_j(T_1)$, so $T_1 u_j=\lambda_j(T_1) u_j$. Also make sure that the $u_j$ are orthogonal (this is automatic, except in the case of degeneracies). Then
$$
\lambda_n(T_1)=\langle u_n, T_1 u_n\rangle =\inf_{v\perp u_1,\ldots , u_{n-1}} \langle v, T_1 v\rangle < \inf _{v\perp u_1,\ldots , u_{n-1}} \langle v, T_2 v\rangle .
$$
The inequality is true because the infima are really minima: by the assumption on the existence of discrete spectrum in the range we're investigating and by the spectral theorem, the search for $v$ can be restricted to a suitable finite-dimensional subspace. We can then try the $v$ that minimizes $\langle v, T_2 v\rangle$ in the other quadratic form.

We're done since obviously $\lambda_n(T_2)\ge \inf _{v\perp u_1,\ldots , u_{n-1}} \langle v, T_2 v\rangle$.

---

The argument can also be organized differently, maybe this version is more transparent: Let $M\subseteq H$, $\dim M=n$, be the ("an", in the case of degeneracies) space spanned by the eigenvectors of $T_2$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1(T_2),\ldots , \lambda_n(T_2)$. Then $\max_{v\in M, \|v\|=1 }\langle v, T_2 v\rangle = \lambda_n(T_2)$.

By assumption and since $M$ is finite-dimensional,
$$
t=\max_{v\in M, \|v\|=1 } \langle v, T_1 v\rangle < \lambda_n(T_2) .
$$
For any choice of $u_1,\ldots , u_{n-1}\in H$, there will be a $v\in M\ominus H$, $\|v\|=1$. Hence, by min-max, $\lambda_n(T_1)\le t<\lambda_n(T_2)$.

Comment: Why the second equality in $(\star)$ occurs? Thanks to the ortonality of $u_j$?

Comment: Yes, because $\lambda_n$ is the minimum ev of $T_1$ restricted to $\{ u_1, \ldots , u_{n-1} \}^{\perp}$.

Comment: And what occurs if, for instance,  $\lambda_{n-1}= \lambda_{n}$? Can we to guarantee the orthogonality between $u_{n-1}$ and $u_{n}$? I think not. In this case, is the above argument still valid?

Comment: @Guilherme: In this case, I choose the eigenvectors as orthogonal vectors. (This is exactly what I'm addressing in the sentence "Also, make sure that ...")